# How to toggle OFF the ON, while turning ON the NEW w/o display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.nav li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('navChange');
  });

  $('.sub').on('click', function() {
    $('.subBkgd').toggleClass('subChange');
    $('ul', this).toggleClass('ulChange');

  });

});
```

```css
.subBkgd {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out!important;
  z-index: -10;
}

.subChange {
  visibility: visible!important;
  transform: scaleX(200);
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav ul li {
  font: 400 .75em Verdana, sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
}

.nav ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 2%;
}

.nav ul ul a {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.navChange {
  background-color: #666;
}

.navChange a {
  color: #F00!important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ulChange {
  visibility: visible!important;
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class='subBkgd'></div>

<div class='nav'>
  <ul id='menu'>
    <li><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
    <li class='sub'><a href='#'>DESIGNS ></a>
      <ul>
        <a href='#'>item1</a>
        <a href='#'>item2</a>
        <a href='#'>item3</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='sub'><a href='#'>CUSTOMIZE ></a>
      <ul>
        <a href='#top'>item5</a>
        <a href='#colors'>item6</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='sub'><a href='#'>FROM SCRATCH></a>
      <ul>
        <a href='#top'>item7</a>
        <a href='#'>item8</a>
        <a href='#'>item9</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>ORDER </a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>OUR STORY </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This code works individually on each menu button (LI), but lacks togglin on buttons that are already on, not to mention needing to toggle everything if the use clicks outside the menu.

```
$('.nav li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('navChange'); 
});

$('.sub').on('click', function() {
  $('.subBkgd').toggleClass('subChange');
  $('ul', this).toggleClass('ulChange');
});
```

Link to current test nav:

```
http://cardscreative.com/cc2017/test4.html
```

This fiddle looked promising, but i can't seem to adapt it to my specific situation:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/29j3e/1/
```

My "newbie" problem: Need jquery (3.3.1?) code to toggle nav buttons that have a UL and an underneath transitioned div (for effect), such that when clicked, the NEW LI toggles the 'ON' sibling 'OFF' & everything under it including the transitioned div, while turning on the NEW LI, it's UL & toggling the transitioned div again.

I've been all over and tried .sibling, .each, .filter, and mostly made a hash of it. Please check out the fiddle below for what's working so far. I've removed all other non-working experimental code. (Sub UL's only have links, no LI's for arrangement purposes.) Thanks for any help and wisdom. Really want to learn this stuff! (This part of jquery seems to have become a real rabbit hole for me!)

link to half working js:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/jvxcc0Lw/48/
```

Also, for mobile purposes, I'm trying to avoid using :hover.

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Updated the code to make it more readable.

```js
 $('.list-item').on('click', function() {
   $('.list-item').not(this).removeClass('activeItem')
     .children('.sub-Menu').removeClass('showSubMenu');
   $(this).toggleClass('activeItem');
   $(this).children('.sub-Menu').toggleClass('showSubMenu')
 });
```

```css
#menu {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.subChange {
  visibility: visible !important;
  transform: scaleX(200);
}

.nav ul li {
  font: 400 .75em Verdana, sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
}

.sub-Menu {
  visibility: hidden !important;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 2%;
  width: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition: width .25s ease-in-out !important;
}

.sub-Menu a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.activeItem {
  background-color: #666;
}

.activeItem a {
  color: #F00 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.showSubMenu {
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="effectsBackground"></div>
<div class='nav'>
  <ul id='menu'>
    <li class="list-item"><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href='#'>DESIGNS ></a>
      <ul class="sub-Menu">
        <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href='#'>CUSTOMIZE ></a>
      <ul class="sub-Menu">
        <li><a href='#top'>item5</a></li>
        <li><a href='#colors'>item6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href='#'>FROM SCRATCH></a>
      <ul class="sub-Menu">
        <li><a href='#top'>item7</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>item8</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>item9</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href='#'>ORDER </a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href='#'>OUR STORY </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The Main magic is on this 
`$('.list-item').not(this).removeClass('activeItem')`
the line selects all the list-item except the current one and removes the activeItem class.

```
   ` .children('.sub-Menu').removeClass('showSubMenu');`
```

now since we have already filtered the parent and with the help of chaining we will just select the children sub-Menu and remove the showSubmenu

Edit:
Updated the html Mark Up of Sub Item and now instead of using a outside div, just using the sub-Menu transition for width to provide the effect

Comment: Thanks Shah, You've answered the main part of the problem. I'll play and see if I can get the background part to work with this. I'll let you know!

Comment: @Cardguy Check out the updated code, its working with background effect.

Comment: Hi Shah, the issue of the outside div is to get the underlying transition started from the MIDDLE of the menu, specifically NOT underneath the LI (where you usually might expect it to be left justified). My research (which could be wrong) showed that submenu transitions always started on one side or the other. I'm trying to get both the submenu links and whatever background gets used to open from the middle of the whole menu, and not just directly under the LI. (see my "text nav" link up above to see the bkgd in action.) Is this a case for an "if" statement?

Comment: so if i am understanding it correctly you want the effect to cover the whole bottom portion and no-matter which menu item is selected the sub menu should always start from the middle, is that what you want ?

Comment: yes, but with the transition starting in the middle, and spreading to both sides. P.S. thanks so much for your help on this. Super appreciated! here's the original transition: [link] (http://cardscreative.com/cc2017/test4.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you add,modify after: function() {

> function(e,ui) { if (e.target == this)